# NX nest app: how to access environment variables from dist

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, nestjs, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have such a project structure:

[image: structure]

I'm using nx with nest.
In my `app.module.ts` file, i configure `ConfigModule` so that it reads the `.env` file depending on `NODE_ENV`, and then I use it to connect to MongoDB

```
const envFilePath = `../envs/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() || 'development'}`;

@Module({
   imports: [
      ConfigModule.forRoot({
         envFilePath,
         isGlobal: true
      }),
      MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
         imports: [ConfigModule],
         inject: [ConfigService],
         useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
            console.log(configService.get<string>('MONGO_URI'));
            return {
               uri: configService.get<string>('MONGO_URI')
            };
         }
      })
   ],
   controllers: [AppController],
   providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But `configService.get<string>('MONGO_URI')` always returns `undefined`, and here's why: if you output the `__filename` constant to the console, its value will be `<absolute-path>\dist\apps\backend\main.js`. That is, all paths in the file are considered relative to the `dist` folder, which is located in the root of the nx project.

**Question**: how do I make env files accessible by relative paths from src. I don't want to make a path from dst to src, as it will be very unstable and wrong.

There was an idea to store configs in `.ts` files, but I don't like this option either, because there should be code in such files, not stored data

Answer (score 0):

Solution: all I had to do was move the envs folder to the root of the nx project

Answer (score 0):

1. root creation .env file
2. use copy assets

```json
"assets": [
    {
      "input": "apps/project/src/envs",
      "glob": "**/*.env",
      "output": "."
    },
],
```